# The verb "to move" to express the idea of arousing someone's sexual desire

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Here goes [Mary Magdalene's solo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-ChyH9RHfY) in the Jesus Christ Super Star rock opera:

> I don't know how to love him.
>
> What to do, how to move him.

And then, there comes:

> I don't know how to take this.
>
> I don't see why he moves me.

Does the verb ***move*** here mean to inflame/ get inflamed sexually? If yes, could someone kindly suggest a couple of common, maybe idiomatic, expressions of the same connotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some other words that mean similar things to what you're looking for would be:

> seduce
>   turn on
>   get somebody going
>   get hot

Answer (score 1):

To be **moved** is to be affected emotionally.  Its meaning is very broad, not specific to sexual arousal.

> She found the speech very moving.
>
> The speech really moved the audience.

In context it could refer to feelings of love or attraction, but it would do so in a very general way.  Unless otherwise qualified, the word **move** suggests *heartfelt* or *deep* emotion.

Comment: Just an emotional impact upon? As easy as that? Then why would Marry Magdalena ask herself how she could make one? Part of the question may seem to be answered, Even if someone asking a question should have looked up the word in a dictionary before asking – I swear I did -- what about the other part?

Comment: I don't follow the logic of your comment. Why would her wondering *how* to move him have anything to do with the meaning of the word **move**?  The word is simply not as specific as you want it to be.

Comment: To ask if the word **move** means "to get someone sexually aroused" is like asking if the verb "prepare" means "to chop" or "to dice".   These are general, encompassing verbs, not narrow, specific verbs.

Comment: There's a touch of desperation in Marry's asking "how can I" and "why he does", isn't there? So in short, what's it about (seducing or what else)--this is the first part of the question--and the variants of expressing the same idea, this is the second.

Comment: @Rompey:  We can't get into discussing her motives here. That would be to stray into off-topic territory. That said, she could be trying to "reach him" in a way that does not involve her sexuality.  **move** is broad enough in its meaning to include arousing someone's passions but by no means does it entail that sense.